# JSON post of complex type with two constructors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to send a JSON post to an MVC controller; my type is like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<B> list { get; set; }

    public class B
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public B(C c)
        {
            ...
        }

        public B(D d)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The way I'm sending is:

```
var A = {};
var B = {};
A.Name = "testRe";

A.list = [];
B.Name = "testCat1";
A.list.push(B);
B = {};
B.Name = "testCat2";
A.list.push(B);

$.ajax({
    url: "/ExportModels/saveRelease",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(A)
}).done(function (result) {

});
```

It all works well if the constructor for B would be a plain one but for my logic B can only have C or D objects (not both). But then I can't do post.

Is there a way do do a JSON post for a type B object?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom model binder? See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413313/posting-data-when-my-view-model-has-a-constructor-does-not-work.

Comment: This won't work out the box, the default model binder requires a parameterless constructor.