# ASP.Net Core Exception - Could not create a model binder for model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I am still new to MVC and I am struggling to resolve an issue where the default binding is failing on form submit to a controller expecting a view model.  I have tried adding model binding attributes [FromForm] to the constructor with no success and I have started to read about custom binders but that feel overkill in this case.  If I need to post the full HTML I can do.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this, all help greatly appreciated?  I am struggling to even debug and hit breakpoints.

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create a model binder for model object >of type 'XX.Models.ClientEditViewModel'.

MODEL

```
public partial class ClientEditViewModel
{
  public ClientEditViewModel(List<ProgramViewModel> programs)
  {
    this.Programs = programs;
  }
  public int ClientId { get; set; }
  public string ClientName { get; set; }
  public List<ProgramViewModel> Programs { get; set; }
}
```

FORM

```
@model XX.Models.ClientEditViewModel
<form asp-action="EditClient" method="post">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ClientId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.ClientName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="@Model.ClientName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ClientName" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditClient(ClientEditViewModel clientedit)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Client client = await dbcontext.Client.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == clientedit.ClientId);
    try
    {
        client.Name = clientedit.ClientName;
        dbcontext.Client.Update(client);
        await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        if (!ClientExists(clientedit.ClientId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    TempData["msg"] = "You have successfully edited " + clientedit.ClientName + ".";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default binding uses a parameterless constructor, while your model has a custom constructor which would require a custom binding. Here is a similar post [Posting data when my view model has a constructor does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413313/posting-data-when-my-view-model-has-a-constructor-does-not-work)

In your case, Programs has a setter, so I would remove the custom constructor completely.

Comment: the question is a duplicate, so the answer is redundant

Comment: The constructor was the issue, thank you for taking the time to answer.  My question turned out to be a duplicate but that is because i did not search with those terms.

Your answer was very helpful, I have voted it as such and upmarked it.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad that I could help. This was my first answer that I have provided!